# Center cursor in TextField Flutter

Tags: flutter

In a stock android SMS client. You Have limited height space for your input. If you scroll that input, the cursor moves and stays in view. Google Translate has that too.
How can you do that in flutter (Moving and changing cursor's position to stay in view if scrolling gets it out of view)?
[image]

Comment: Check the `maxLines` attribute of the TextFIeld.

Comment: I have it as 12. But what's after that? How the cursor can be positioned to a specific line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.